# Trying to clear entries but i only clear the last one

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I create a function to bind it with a but so when i press the button all all the entries in my programm will be cleared. When i run the function, only the last one is being cleared.

P.S. all the entries are generated with `for`, in the same way i try to clear them.

```py
def refresh():
    for i in range (1,a+1):
        entrylength_i.delete(0, "end")
        entrywidth_i.delete(0, "end")
        entryheight_i.delete(0, "end")
    for j in range (1,b+1):
        entrylength_j.delete(0, "end")
        entrywidth_j.delete(0, "end")
        entryheight_j.delete(0, "end")
```

Comment: I don't think `entrylength_i` is what you are expecting. It would be much easier if you append your entries to a list when you first generated in the `for` loop, and loop through that list later to clear instead.

Comment: I created a list called "e" to `append` the entries when i create them. Then i clear the list, using `e.clear()`. But nothing happens.

Comment: You only cleared the references to the objects in your list. To properly clear the content in each entries, use `for entry in e: entry.delete(0, "end")`

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!! Just for educational reasons, in the first function i posted, did i make any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you created your entries the same way you try to clear them, I assume you do something like:

```
a= 5
e = []

for i in range (1,a+1):
    entrylength_i = tk.Entry(root)
    entrylength_i.grid(row=i,column=0)
    e.append(entrylength_i)

print (e)
```

Result:

```
[<tkinter.Entry object .!entry>, <tkinter.Entry object .!entry2>, ...]
```

In the `for` loop, you are reusing the variable name `entrylength_i` over and over (instead of `entrylength_1`, `entrylength_2`...). It works because you are creating a new object in each iteration.

But when you try to remove them using the same technique:

```
for i in range (1,a+1):
    entrylength_i.delete(0, "end")
```

The variable `entrylength_i` only points to the object it last defined, which is why only last one is being cleared.

Therefore the proper way to clear all the entries is to iterate through the objects in your list `e`:

```
for entry in e:
    entry.delete(0, "end")
```

Comment: i did it just like you said, only with one difference, i let the user to choose `a` . So, in this case how am i able to define how many entries i have to do it the right way? (`entrylength_1`,`entrylength_2`....)

Comment: You can continue what you are doing, but understand that you are using the same variable name over and over (which is how most people do when they use a loop to make a bunch of widgets). As long as you keep a reference to the widgets by appending to a list, you can manipulate them later by looping through the list or indexing.

Comment: i think that the variable name changes every time the loop works. For example:
for i=1 
entrylength_i=entrylength_1
am i wrong?

Comment: Only the variable `i` changes in every iteration. Your variable `entrylength_i` is not related to `i` and will only stay the same.

Comment: oh, i see. Is there any way to make the variable name change in every time loop works?
P.S. I appreciate your help a lot, because i am selfstudied and i obviouly, don't know that much.

Comment: Actually there is seldom a need to change the variable name in every iteration. If you really need to keep a reference, use a `dict` instead.